# What is the word for the gesture when someone takes three fingers and kisses it into the air?

Tags: italian, gestures

You often see this with Italians, especially when complimenting some food they just ate, but it has evolved into a more universal gesture.

Take the thumb, index, and middle finger, gather them together, bring them to your lips, and kiss them, while moving your arm away and spread your fingers, while saying MWAH!

Is there a single word for this gesture?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but [this video](https://youtu.be/aHZwYObN264?t=2m3s) shows a ton of Italian gestures and they're fun. You should see. I've linked it to the relevant part. See if that helps.

Comment: That's not a gesture used by English-speaking countries so I'm not sure you'd find an English word for it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a pure English word. It could be a borrow.

Answer (score 8):

In English, the word used is **‘chef’s kiss’**.

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/chefs-kiss/):

> *Chef's kiss* is a gesture and expression meant to show something is perfect or excellent. The gesture is made by pinching the fingers and thumb of one hand together (often in an OK sign), kissing them, and then tossing them dramatically away from the lips. Its tone can be sincere or ironic.

> [image: chef's kiss]

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/chefs-kiss-internet-meme-phrase-origin

Answer (score 2):

well  I will say: 'magnifico!'

Comment: yes, that's the expression! i'm wondering if there's a name for the gesture itself.

Comment: or "che gusto" (*What a taste"*)

Answer (score 2):

If you call it "finger kiss" or "italian finger kiss" just about everyone will know what you're referring to.

If you want to be correct though, it's "al bacio".